# How can I get the error status codes from a Vuex response?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to handle errors in my Laravel/Vue application. As far as I can tell, I have everything in place as I am seeing what I expect. However, I am unable to get/return the status code if the response is anything other than `200`.

```
console.log('status: ', response.status); // 200
```

If the response is `400` (or anything other than 200), I am unable to read it.

```
console.log('status: ', response.status); // undefined
```

Here is what I am creating for a response in my Controller:

**Controller.php**

```
...

if ($exception->getCode() === 400) {
    return response()->json(['errors' =>
        [
            'title' => 'Bad Request',
            'detail' => 'The username or password you have entered is invalid',
        ],
    ], $exception->getCode());
}
```

In the network tab, the response *is* coming back as `400`, and the response object looks like this:

```
{"errors":{"title":"Bad Request","detail":"The username or password you have entered is invalid"}}
```

Awesome!

The request in my Vue component looks like this (click event handler):

```
...

try {
    await this.$store.dispatch("user/signInWithEmailAndPassword", this.form)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('status: ', response.status);

                switch (response.status) {
                    case 200:
                        console.log('good to go!');
                        break;
                    case 400:
                        console.log('400 error');  // not getting here
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        console.log('401 error');  // or here
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('some other error');  // end up here all the time
                        break;
                    }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('SignInForm.authenticate error: ', error);
        });
} catch (error) {
    console.log("SignInForm.handleSubmit catch error:", error);
}
```

In my Vuex store, I am just returning the response from my service to see what I'm getting:

**Vuex Store.vue**

```
return await UserService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials)
        .then(response => {
            return response;

        ...
```

**UserService.vue**

```
...

return await client.post('/v1/login', credentials)
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('UserService.signInWithEmailAndPassword error: ', error); // getting here
        return error;
    });
```

So far, the only luck I'm having is seeing this in my console:

> UserService.signInWithEmailAndPassword error:  Error: Request failed with status code 400

How can I read the `400` error code to show the error I really want? It seems all the pieces are there. I'm not handling the error response correctly. Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

I have updated my code to reflect your suggestions, and I believe it stems from not returning my `UserService` call correctly. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
return await client.post('/v1/login', credentials)
        .then(user => {
            console.log('user: ', user);

            return user;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);

            return error;
        });
```

When I provide an invalid un/pw, I am getting into the catch, and seeing the `error` message which is:

> error:  Error: Request failed with status code 400

I am failing to properly return it though. As in, the code that calls this method is always ending up in the `.then` and not in the `.catch` block.

I feel like this is a really simple thing that I'm making incredibly difficult. Thank you for your help!

Comment: anything other than 200 will be going to catch block, so, ideally, you switch logic shall be in the catch block.

Comment: Thank you @ShivamSingh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`then` is called when the the status is: `status >= 200 && status < 300`. Errors are catched in the `catch` method. The above code should be changed like this:

```
try {
    await this.$store.dispatch("user/signInWithEmailAndPassword", this.form)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('status: ', response.status);
            console.log('good to go!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
                switch (error.response.status) {
                    case 400:
                        console.log('400 error');  // not getting here
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        console.log('401 error');  // or here
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('some other error');  // end up here all the time
                        break;
                    }

            console.log('SignInForm.authenticate error: ', error);
        });
} catch (error) {
    console.log("SignInForm.handleSubmit catch error:", error);
}
```

Of course you can destruct the error and get the response directly

```
.catch(({ response }) => {
                switch (response.status) {
```

**UPDATE**

You should also properly return the error from the service:

```
return await client.post('/v1/login', credentials)
        .then(user => {
            console.log('user: ', user);

            return user;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);

            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
```

Comment: I think I figured it out - your explanation was a tremendous help. I added `return Promise.reject(error);` to the catch block. Can you include that in your answer and I'll check it? It's such a great explanation.

Comment: I'm glad that you've figured that out. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a const variable in your js getting the content of a file which returns an array of key->value and then accessing it from your js with the error message.

Example of config file:

```
return [
    "200" => "Todo bien",
    "201" => "Todo mal"
];
```

Vue file:

```
showItems()
{
    axios.get('shopping-cart').then(response => {

        if ( response.status != 200 ) return this.error = this.errors[response.status];
        this.items = response.data;

    }).catch(error => this.error = error);
}
```